# Preserve whitespace and formatting for text returned from $.get jquery call

Tags: formatting, jquery

I have a jquery $.get() call in my app that requests an entire web page. In the callback function, I access a div in the returned page, get its data and show it on my page.

The problem is that the text I get from the div does not preserve the source formatting. If the div in the requested page had say an ordered list, then when i get that text and display on my page, it shows up as a paragraph with items inline instead of being shown as a list.

I do not know whether the problem is how $.get() is getting the data or in my displaying of the data.

```
//get the page
        $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(data){
                callbackFunc(data,myLink);
            }, 
            "html");

  function callbackFunc(responseText, customData){

        //response has bg color of #DFDFDF
        var td = $("td[bgcolor='#DFDFDF']", responseText);

        //text to show is in div of that td
        var forumText = $('div', td).text();

        //append new row with request data below the current row in my table
        var currentRow = $(customData).parent('td').parent('tr');
        var toAppend = "<tr><td class='myTd' colspan='3'>" + forumText + "</td></tr>";

        $(currentRow).after(toAppend);
}
```

The response data shows up like ABC in the new row I add to my div while the source page div had 
A
B
C

I should add that this script is part of an extension for Google Chrome so that is my only browser that I have tested on

Answer (score 2):

Try using .html instead of .text:

```
var forumText = $('div', td).html();
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this thread because I needed to preserve the formatting too. However using .html() instead of .text() is not an option because someone could inject a JavaScript attack this way. I found the solution I was looking for on [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726970/how-to-preserve-newlines-when-showing-a-text-file-with-jquery).

So for example, change the following lines in your code to preserve white space while still using .text() using the white-space CSS style:

```
var toAppend = '<tr><td class="myTd" colspan="3" style="white-space: pre-line;">' 
+ forumText + "</td></tr>";
```