# How do I apply line break in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a javascript object property that is retrieved from database.

It has something like

```
This is line one
This is line two
This is line three
This is the line four
```

My problem is when I want to show them in my html page, there is no break line and they are all cramp together like:

```
this is line one this is line two this is line three this is the line four
```

Is there anyway I can show the line break with Javascript only?

Thanks.

Comment: What does your JS look like?

Comment: just var string = obj.string. and obj.string has the contents I mentioned above

Comment: how are you getting the data from the db into the page?

Comment: @j08691 I got it from webservice.

Comment: Are there any special character separating the content in between lines? Otherwise it will be impossible unless you get the data differently

Comment: If the value of `obj.string` contains line break characters, the containing element can be styled with [`white-space: pre-line`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) to display them. [How to preserve newlines when showing a text file with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726970/how-to-preserve-newlines-when-showing-a-text-file-with-jquery)

Comment: You can replace the newline characters with HTML line break elements, but you can also do it with CSS. @JonathanLonowski, you should make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace new lines (`\n`) with `<br>` tags:

```
replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
```

See example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jD864/).

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher: `\r` hasn't been all that common since pre OSX days.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher Unix-like systems (Linux, OS X) use `\n`, Windows uses `\r\n`. In either case, replacing `\n` is enough. It's unlikely that data is separated by only `\r`.

Answer (score 2):

Line breaks are just treated as spaces in HTML.

You can display the string in a `<pre>` tag, then the line breaks are used as line breaks.

You can replace the line breaks with `<br>` tags:

```
s = s.replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>');
```

Answer (score 1):

insert a `<br />` between the lines

Comment: I can't do that in DB because I don't have control of the data

Comment: `<br>`is enough. Replace `\n` by `<br>` after reading from the database.

Comment: is each line its own piece of data or all one long line?

Answer (score 1):

If you're adding this to the HTML Document, `<br />` should work. But in only-JS solutions, you should use `\r\n` for CRLF.

Answer (score 1):

```
var string = "this is line one this is line two this is line three this is the line four";

var stringNewLine = string.replace('this', '<br/>this');
```

This is an extreme edge case and will only work with this example.

Comment: I believe the OP has \n or \r\n between the strings, but I admit it isn't clear from the question.

Answer (score 1):

Odds are your DB has the data stored with a line-break character.

Because there are three different line break characters used out in the wild, I tend to choose a process that will work on all three.

```
var line="MSDOS line end\r\nUnix line end\nOld Mac line end\r";
var converted = line.replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g, "<br>");
```