# How to load each line from a text file into HTML list using jQuery and Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a basic log file like below:

```
Admin Login at 3:00
User A Login at 3:10
User B Login at 3:12
User M Login at 3:17
User D Login at 3:30
User E Login at 3:42
Admin Login at 4:00
User A Login at 4:03
User F Login at 4:15
.....
```

and I am using this jQuery Ajax call to list the logins:

```
<div >
    <ul id="result">

    </ul>
</div>
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: "data.txt",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function (data) {
       $('#result').append('<li>'+data+'</li>');
    },
    async: false
});
</script>
```

but (as expected!) I am loading all of the text file to only one `<li>` and the result look like:

> . Admin Login at 3:00 User A Login at 3:10 User B Login at 3:12 User M 
>   Login at 3:17 User D Login at 3:30 User E Login at 3:42 Admin Login at > 4:00 User A Login at 4:03 User F Login at 4:15

How can I load each row of the text file into one separate `<li>`?

Comment: What is the format of `data`, is it a list or is it just one big string?

Comment: Your newlines are being ignored. Someone had a similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726970/how-to-preserve-newlines-when-showing-a-text-file-with-jquery

Comment: @jwang brings up a good point, Did you want the full text inside the `<li>` tag? like a `<pre>` tag that preserves new lines? or an `<li>` tag per each line of text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the data by line separators:

```
$.each(data.split(/[\n\r]+/), function(index, line) {
  $('<li>').text(line).appendTo('#result');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sukirma, this is exactly what I want

Comment: Also note that the `$.ajax` method returns a jQuery deferred object so the need to deep indent a success property as a call back is antiquated and less flexible. See [`.then()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) for details

Comment: sure but I have to wait for 10 min to accept the answer as correct answer!